# git ls-tree with git hash-object

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to get the latest versions of all files with file hashes in a repository in a text file.
For this I've written a simple powershell script

```
foreach ($s in git ls-tree -r --name-status HEAD)
{
    if($s.StartsWith(".")) {    
    } else {
        try {
            write-host "$((git log -1 --format="%ci" -- $s).SubString(0, 19))|$(git hash-object "$s")|$s"
            write-output "$((git log -1 --format="%ci" -- $s).SubString(0, 19))|$(git hash-object "$s")|$s" >> .\output\git_change.txt
        } catch { }
    }
}
```

The only problem is our repository contains 11k files and executing the `git hash-object` takes around 500ms for each file.
Is there any way to get this script to execute faster?

Comment: Not if it's the hash calculating taking time. How long does it take to hash per file?

Comment: If I calculate the hash with powerhsell via `Get-FileHash` it takes ~100ms. It's a bit better, but still quite slow. Is there any other possibl way?

Comment: Well, who says it's the `hash-object` command that takes so long? `git log -- file` can be pretty costly depending on the commit history. Set `$env:GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE = 1` to have `git` emit performance trace output

Comment: git log is acutally quite fast. I think I'll just write a small .net app to calculate everything.

Answer (score 1):

`git hash-object` will recompute the hash of each file from its content on disk.

If you are not looking to recompute, but juste want the hash for the last *versioned* content for the file, you can maybe look at :

```
git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}
```

and recursively dig into sub trees